# Com limitar o resultado do Select no Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, select

Estou fazendo um select do banco e ele esta me retornando 15 linhas. Usei o ROWNUM para pegar as 8 primeiras linhas, só que quero fazer outro select e pegar da linha 9 a 15.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT o.STORAGE_TYPE, COUNT(o.QUANTIDADE) as 
qtd_materiais   
FROM mopsao.vw_monitoramento_do@MOPSAO m INNER JOIN VIEW_ORDENS_A_COLETAR o 
ON 
m.DELIVERY = o.DELIVERY AND m.cod_mat_c = o.MATERIAL WHERE 
m.status_andamento = 'Pickado' 
GROUP BY o.STORAGE_TYPE ORDER BY qtd_materiais DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 8
```

Esse primeiro select como descrevi, pegam as 8 primeiras linhas.

Comment: o ROWnum server para limitar os registros mesmo, aparentemente você quer fazer uma tratativa de paginação para sua aplicação, correto? Neste caso você precisa tratar na sua aplicação o fetch dos registros do banco, limitando de 8 em  8 registros. Você pode procurar algo específico na biblioteca que você usa para fazer a conexão com o oracle, provavelmente vai ter uma explicação mais completa de como realizar a paginação

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia amigo, para tal demanda, é necessário usar o FETCH passando como parâmetro a quantidade de linhas que você quer no intervalo.

Exemplo:
Offset -> Quantidade de linhas
Fetch -> Offset + Intervalo de linhas

```
DECLARE @Off AS INT
SET @Off = @OFFSET
SELECT Coluna1, Coluna2
  FROM Tabela
  OFFSET (@Off) ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Substitui os Offset que estão em maiusculo para o numero de linhas que quero exibir, mas não deu certo

Comment: Guilherme, conforme já comentei ali na pergunta, tenta dar uma olhada na ferramenta que você utiliza para conectar sua aplicação com o oracle, 99% de chance dela ter recursos para controlar o fetch/paginação, no caso a própria ferramenta faz estes passos que foi respondido pelo @fabiano-s.

Answer (score 1):

Isso deve resolver seu caso:
SELECT lin.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT o.STORAGE_TYPE, COUNT(o.QUANTIDADE) as 
                             qtd_materiais, rownum as linha
                      FROM mopsao.vw_monitoramento_do@MOPSAO m INNER JOIN V 
                      IEW_ORDENS_A_COLETAR o 
                      ON 
                      m.DELIVERY = o.DELIVERY AND m.cod_mat_c = o.MATERIAL WHERE 
                      m.status_andamento = 'Pickado' 
                      GROUP BY o.STORAGE_TYPE ORDER BY qtd_materiais DESC) lin
where lin.linha <= 8

Comment: Não funcionou, ainda continua dando erro

Comment: qual o erro? fiz uns testes aqui e funcionou,

Comment: Apareceu este erro ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Quero pegar da linha 8 ate a linha 16. Desse modo que vc fez, esta exibindo o erro a cima